# LEFT JOIN not working as it should

Tags: php, mysqli, left-join

I'm using LEFT JOIN to only retrieve the latest db entry of a visitor based on the visitors IP for my applications. Somehow it doesnt work correctly. Whenever I use 'AND m1.application_id = '7'' it gets all the connections for the application with 7 as ID. Whenever I try to get the connections for the application with 8 as ID, there is no result while there are connections stored in the database. Am I doing something wrong?

```
SELECT m1.* FROM `tumblr_tracker` m1
LEFT JOIN `tumblr_tracker` m2
ON (m1.ip_address = m2.ip_address AND m1.visit_id < m2.visit_id)
WHERE m2.visit_id IS NULL AND m1.application_id = '8'
ORDER BY m1.visit_id
DESC LIMIT 20
```

### **Edited**

What I'm trying to do is as following: I'm storing every Tumblr visit in my database. The data I store is as following: visit_id, ip_address, postal_code, city, region, country, timestamp. So when someone visits my Tumblr, a new entry is being stored in my database. I'd like to show these visits in my adminpanel based on the latest visit timestamp (which is gonna be in the highest visit_id entry for the users ip_address), but I do not want to show the duplicate entries.

So basically: user with ip address: 88.88.88.88 visits my page 5 times, there will be 5 entries in my database with that ip_address. I only want to see all the data of the latest entry.

My db table is called '**tumblr_tracker**'. I have the followings columns:
- visit_id (AUTO INCREMENT)
- application_id 
- ip_address
- postal_code
- city
- region
- country
- network
- timestamp

**This is my current code:**

```
$show_tumblr_connections = array(); 
$get_tumblr_connections = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT m1.* FROM `tumblr_tracker` m1 LEFT JOIN `tumblr_tracker` m2 ON (m1.ip_address = m2.ip_address AND m1.visit_id < m2.visit_id) WHERE m1.application_id = '".$db_application_id."' AND m2.visit_id IS NULL ORDER BY m1.visit_id DESC LIMIT 20") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($get_tumblr_connections)){
    $tumblr_connections_array = array( 'ip_address' => $row['ip_address'],
    'postal_code' => $row['postal_code'],
    'city' => $row['city'],
    'region' => $row['region'],
    'country' => $row['country'],
    'network' => $row['network'],
    'timestamp' => $row['timestamp']);
    $show_tumblr_connections[] = $tumblr_connections_array;
}
```

Comment: This sounds like maybe your own query got ahead of you.  Are you sure that there are records for `application_id = '8'` _and_ `m2.visit_id IS NULL` ?

Comment: It might be useful to post the table definitions and some sample data

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen m2.visit_id IS NULL seems to be the problem. However, removing that from my query will show all the connections a user made with the App rather than just one.

Comment: The logic of your query is flawed.  You compare `m2.visit_id` in the `ON` clause.  But in order for the `WHERE` clause to be true, the `ON` clause will return `NULL` and you will never get any results.  Please update your question with what you are trying to do so that we may rewrite your query.  A schema would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your query is that it finds the data for the last visit from each IP address before taking the application_id into consideration. When you then filter on application_id, you will only get results for IP adresses where the last visit is related to that application_id.

In order to correct your query, you will have to modify the `JOIN` condtition to consider the application_id as well, like this:

```
SELECT m1.* FROM `tumblr_tracker` m1
LEFT JOIN `tumblr_tracker` m2
ON (m1.ip_address = m2.ip_address
    AND m1.application_id = m2.application_id
    AND m1.visit_id < m2.visit_id)
WHERE m2.visit_id IS NULL AND m1.application_id = '8'
ORDER BY m1.visit_id DESC
LIMIT 20
```